# how to make calculation in JavaScript with below formula?

Tags: javascript, math

Formula is :

```
x = (a(b))/(1-(1+a)^-c)
```

I need to calculate value of `x (^-c: -c is power to (1+a))`

If you have done this kind of calculations with dynamic values please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Math.pow(x, y)` to compute `x ^ y`, or `x` to the power of `y`:

```
x = (a*b) / (1 - Math.pow(1+a, -c))
```

Or as @Patrick suggested in his comment below with ES7 we could use the `**` operator, in which case your assignment would become:

```
x = (a*b) / (1 - ((1+a)**-c))
```

Comment: Or `**` operator

Comment: @Kaiido That link shows support on Opera, and I also just checked Safari version 10, works on that as well.

Comment: @Kaiido I believe node was v6.9.2 for most of the ES7 features. **Edit** Nevermind, you are correct. And as for Opera, I was not aware of that, but okay.